# Google+ share link

Tags: android, share, google-plus, google-plus-one

I'm looking for equivalent of facebook sharer link (`http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://stackoverflow.com`) in Google+. I can't use the regular +1 button as I need to embed it in Android application, but I want it to work similar - launch a website to +1 specified url. How do I do it? Or maybe there's some other supported way to embed +1 button in Android application?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official Google+ Share Link is now available here:
https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/share/#sharelink

Example usage:

> https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: how can i get the share button click event? is there any other way to share content and return back to previous once it is shared.

Answer (score 3):

you can use following URL to get the Google+ share link.

```
https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/confirm?hl=en&url=YOUR-WEBSITE
```

Answer (score 2):

Concerning that simple-static-link-approach: [this (German) forum entry](http://www.google.de/support/forum/p/webmasters/thread?tid=7dcea558a276962f&hl=de) states that such a link *does not exist*. I don't know how reliable this is (as it seems to be a user-to-user forum), but it's still more than I've been able to find on the official pages.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a google+ api: https://developers.google.com/+/api/ , you can integrate it inside your application.

Google+ library download: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Android

Comment: have u tried with using that api to share text on your wall y i am asking is bcz of the note given at api link is The Google+ API currently provides read-only access to public data

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(Proyecto.this)
                              .setType("text/plain")
                              .setText(shareUsuario +" - "+ shareProyecto)
                              .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(getResources().getString(R.string.urlMeetinarts) + "work/" + shareId))
                              .getIntent();             
                            startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);
```